# Python Beguiner : Error about raise FileCreateError(e) xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError: [Errno 2] No such file or director

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, dataframe, nlp

I ma trying to save  the result of my prediction in a specific directory but I am getting this error. I am working on a server :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 311, in close
    self._store_workbook()
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 627, in _store_workbook
    raise e
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 625, in _store_workbook
    allowZip64=self.allow_zip64)
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1207, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ge/kelo/eXP/Corpus/lexique_3e_res_LT/test_modelTraditionnel_lexicon_tfidf_ngramBigModel_SVC.xlsx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "features.py", line 228, in <module>
    classify_essai(data_id,data,ylabels)
  File "features.py", line 216, in classify_essai
    output.to_excel("/home/ge/kelo/eXP/Corpus/lexique_3e_res_LT/test_modelTraditionnel_lexicon_tfidf_ngramBig{}.xlsx".format(model_name))
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2256, in to_excel
    engine=engine,
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py", line 742, in write
    writer.save()
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlsxwriter.py", line 195, in save
    return self.book.close()
  File "/home/ge/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 313, in close
    raise FileCreateError(e)
xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ge/kelo/eXP/Corpus/lexique_3e_res_LT/test_modelTraditionnel_lexicon_tfidf_ngramBigModel_SVC.xlsx'
```

Below my script :

```
for model_name, model in models.items():
        y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X_data, ylabels, cv=cv_splitter)
        all_accuracies = cross_val_score(model, X_data, ylabels, cv=cv_splitter)

        print("Model: {}".format(model_name))

        print(all_accuracies)
        print(all_accuracies.mean()) #moyenne  print("Accuracy: {}".format(accuracy_score(ylabels, y_pred)))   #
        print(all_accuracies.std())  #déterminer la variance

        print(classification_report(ylabels, y_pred, labels=labels))
        print("Accuracy: {}".format(accuracy_score(ylabels, y_pred)))
        cm = confusion_matrix(ylabels, y_pred)
        print("matrice confusion: {}".format(cm))

        # export des données
        output = pd.DataFrame()
        output['id'] = output_id
        output['Verbatim'] = Verbatim
        output['Expected Output'] = ylabels
        output['Predicted Output'] = y_pred
        # print(output.head())
        #output.to_excel("test_modelTraditionnel_lexicon_tfidf_ngram{}.xlsx".format(model_name))
        output.to_excel("/home/ge/kelo/eXP/Corpus/lexique_3e_res_LT/test_modelTraditionnel_lexicon_tfidf_ngramBig{}.xlsx".format(model_name))
```

How can I overcome it , should I use os.chdir to modify the directory before exporting to the specific directory or is there a better solution ?

Comment: Have you checked that the file path is correct? It's not directly related to the issue, but why are you adding columns to the DataFrame one by one, instead of using the constructor?